# Activate/Create Community using Metadata API

Tags: community, metadata

Please, How can I activate and create Community (Network) using Metadata API?

I've tested NetworkEnabled:

```
MetadataService.OrgPreferenceSettings orgPref = new MetadataService.OrgPreferenceSettings();
orgPref.fullName = 'OrgPref1';
MetadataService.OrganizationSettingsDetail pref = new MetadataService.OrganizationSettingsDetail();
pref.settingName = 'NetworksEnabled';
pref.settingValue = true;
orgPref.preferences = new List<MetadataService.OrganizationSettingsDetail>{pref};
List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> results =
            service.upsertMetadata(
        new MetadataService.Metadata[] { orgPref });
System.debug(results);
```

But I got this error:

> Chatter Domain must be enabled first.

Comment: did you check the 'Tips and Considerations' under [Deploy Your Community with the Metadata API](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But doesn't really help

Comment: you can't do everything via the metadata api to deploy a community - there are still manual steps invovled that you will need to do in the org.